# Запись в файл List<String[]>

Tags: java, filewriter

Есть структура

```
List<String[]> totalFile = new ArrayList<String[]>();
public List<String[]> getFinishFile() {
    return finishFile;
}
public void setFinishFile(List<String[]> finishFile) {
    this.finishFile.addAll(finishFile);
}
```

я записываю ее в файл.

```
public void write(String PATH) {
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(PATH + "\\total.xls", false)) {
        for (String[] row : getTotalFile ()) {
            String text = row[0];
            writer.write(text);
        }
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

в итоге у меня получается эксель файл с длинной строкой в одной первой А0 ячейке. нужно чтобы каждое значение string[] было в своей ячейке, подскажите, как это запрограммировать? спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для создания/редактирования Excel файлов рекомендую использовать библиотеку [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

В вашем случае можно создать файл с расширением .csv и записать туда строки через запятую:

> test1,test2,test3

Таким образом каждая строка будет в новой колонке.
Например, если вы используете Java8, то можно попробовать такой код:

```
    public void write(String PATH) {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(PATH + "\\total.csv", false)) {
            StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
            for (String[] row : getTotalFile()) {
                joiner.add(row[0]);
            }
            writer.write(joiner.toString());
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```